# Wrong tab configuration on Magento

Tags: magento-1.5, magento

I have a huge problem with an magento extension I developed. Localhost everything is fine but when I deploy, it get this error.

Wrong tab configuration

```
#0 [internal function]: Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs->addTab('pricematrix', 'tab_pricematrix')
#1 /var/www/vhosts/discountprint.dk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(347): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#2 /var/www/vhosts/something.dk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(213): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateAction(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#3 /var/www/vhosts/something.dk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(209): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#4 /var/www/vhosts/something.dk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#5 /var/www/vhosts/something.dk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(270): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#6 /var/www/vhosts/something.dk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(263): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(Array, true, true)
#7 /var/www/vhosts/something.dk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php(246): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout(Array)
#8 /var/www/vhosts/something.dk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController->editAction()
#9 /var/www/vhosts/something.dk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(253): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
#10 /var/www/vhosts/something.dk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#11 /var/www/vhosts/something.dk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(340): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#12 /var/www/vhosts/something.dk/httpdocs/app/Mage.php(627): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#13 /var/www/vhosts/something.dk/httpdocs/index.php(80): Mage::run('', 'store')
#14 {main}
```

I Googled it for hours but can't find any useful information. My magento version is 1.5.0.1

Hope you can help

Comment: If someone can just point me in a direction of possible errors it would be great.

Comment: btw, localhost is running a bit newer version 1.5.1.0

Comment: What is the error message itself?

Comment: Wanted to add a comment here. If it's an extension you have developed, check that you have the module name set correctly in the adminhtml.xml. I had this exact same issue when I had a misspelling in the acl xml `module="smartstock"`, it should have been `module="smart_stock">`

Answer (score 11):

You'll get a lot farther if you stop searching Google and start searching your code.

Search for the exception string "Wrong tab configuration"

```
$ ack 'Wrong tab configuration'
Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Tabs.php
108:                throw new Exception(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Wrong tab configuration.'));
112:            throw new Exception(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Wrong tab configuration.'));
```

Look at that, there's only **two** possible places in the entire source tree that could be throwing that exception, both in the `addTab` method your stack-trace indicated was being called. Looking at that code in context

```
public function addTab($tabId, $tab)
{
    if (is_array($tab)) {
        $this->_tabs[$tabId] = new Varien_Object($tab);
    }
    elseif ($tab instanceof Varien_Object) {
        $this->_tabs[$tabId] = $tab;
        if (!$this->_tabs[$tabId]->hasTabId()) {
            $this->_tabs[$tabId]->setTabId($tabId);
        }
    }
    elseif (is_string($tab)) {
        if (strpos($tab, '/')) {
            $this->_tabs[$tabId] = $this->getLayout()->createBlock($tab);
        }
        elseif ($this->getChild($tab)) {
            $this->_tabs[$tabId] = $this->getChild($tab);
        }
        else {
            $this->_tabs[$tabId] = null;
        }

        if (!($this->_tabs[$tabId] instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface)) {
            throw new Exception(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Wrong tab configuration.'));
        }
    }
    else {
        throw new Exception(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Wrong tab configuration.'));
    }
```

It looks like your call is running through the second if/else branch.  Your tab string, `tab_pricematrix`, is used to fetch a child block from the current tab

```
$this->_tabs[$tabId] = $this->getChild($tab);
```

However, it looks like whatever it finds in there **isn't** a child of `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface`.

My guess is that's because the call to `getChild` is returning false because your module hasn't added a tab with the name `tab_pricematrix` to the layout (did you copy the Layout XML files to the new server?)  Without knowing how you've implemented that module, it's impossible to say for sure.

Good luck!

Comment: I'm in the process of removing files of extensions no longer in use and this answer helped me. I did a <br>`grep -rin "tab_pricematrix" *` and found the offending file. (my function wasn't called tab_pricematrix) And it turns out a developer wrote custom overrides to unbreak extension dependencies, which got broken when unused packages removed.

Answer (score 2):

Normally localhost problems that don't appear on a live site are to do with filesystem case sensitivity. Most developers in my experience develop on Windows / Mac OSX, which by default aren't case sensitive. But most production environments are some kind of *nix system. One thing that has tripped me up in the past is having a filename with a capital letter in the middle.

For example if a block is FooBar.php and sits in Mage_Core, when loading the model you must use...

```
Mage::getModel('core/fooBar');
```

The string is automatically ran through ucwords, but obviously any camel casing in your file naming will need to be taken into account when requesting a model/block etc.

Comment: IS it a typo that you have foo with a little f in your example?

Comment: No, the path get's exploded on underlines, and ran through ucwords, meaning that the f will automatically get changed to uppercase. If the class was instead called Foo_Bar, and was a file called Bar.php sat in a Foo folder, you could simply use 'core/foo_bar'.